# Kernel config for ASUS P8Z77-V mainboard series

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I want to build a kernel (3.6 series) for a system with a ASUS P8Z77-V mainboard. Which settings fit to the built in components?

(The ideal answer would contain an example .config for this board.)

```
# lspci 

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev c4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 09)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
06:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9120 SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 12)
07:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
```

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck. I have a custom 3.6.2 kernel on a P8ZZ77-V and everything works (wifi, ethernet, acpi, integrated video, sound).  It might the most trouble free linux system I've ever had.

I've thrown [the .config on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9HC3jVcC), since it is 3K+ lines.  Most of the motherboard related stuff is built in except the atheros wifi drivers, which are modules.  The processor is an i5 -- in any case you can copy this straight into `src/.config` and then make whatever changes you want.

You shouldn't have to use exactly 3.6.2 either; when I upgrade the kernel I usually just copy in my old .config and have a quick look with `make menuconfig`.  The fundamental stuff doesn't change very often.  You could use `make oldconfig` instead (menuconfig does this implicitly).

**[update]** There is an issue with the wireless driver, although it does not seem to affect normal operation.  See [my report here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53771).

Comment: You can nicely compress the kernel `.config` file by deleting blank and comment lines: `grep -v '\(^#\|^$\)' .config` gives a cleaned up version (just remember to `make oldconfig` later), and that doesn't compress too badly (to 25% or so). Perhaps go one step further and delete the `CONFIG_` starting each line? My everything, the bathtub and the kitchen sink configuration here gives some 3K lines.